# Java JSpinner Prevent Letter Insertion

Tags: java, insertion, jspinner, letter

A JSpinner is used to store a number in my application (with a SpinnerNumberModel).

As expected, the spinner doesn't allow invalid characters (letters, symbols, etc.) to be stored. However, those characters do appear in the spinner component when I type them in. As soon as I switch the focus to another component, they disappear.

Is there a way to prevent invalid characters from appearing in the spinner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a DocumentFilter to the editor of the spinner to prevent unwanted character from being added to the Document. You get the editor using code like:

```
JTextField editor = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinner.getEditor()).getTextField();
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a Document Filter](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the getEditor method returns a JComponent, and there's no getTextField method in the JComponent class. Do I need to cast the returned JComponent to something else?

Comment: Yep, a cast was needed.

**"JTextField editor = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinner.getEditor()).getTextField()"**.

You should update your answer for future viewers.